# Render different partials for collection with different models (STI)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, erb, actionview

I have some relation, with different subtypes of model.

```
Class Venchile < ApplicationRecord; end
Class Car < Venchile; end
Class Moto < Venchile; end

@venchiles = Venchile.all
```

I have different partials for them: **cars/_car.html.erb** and **motos/_moto.html.erb**. And then I render entire collection

```
<%= render @venchiles %>
```

And everything work ok. Each model renders its own partial. But I have one more specific partial: **cars/_car_info.html.erb** and **motos/_moto_info.html.erb**

The question is how to render this entire mixed collection @venchiles with different "*_info.html.erb" partials?

Comment: You already noticed that rendering a mixing collection works ok. Why can you follow Rails naming conventions and why do you need the more specific name that breaks these conventions?

Comment: I need to display Venchiles in different contexts. For example with short and full info. And I cant do this within the same partial.

Comment: `= render partial: 'motos/moto_info'`

Answer (score 0):

You should ask yourself:
"why two instance objects from the same model, need different views?"
This might be a sign of unnormalized relation. They might belong to different models or at least they have different types.